# ARRAYFORMULA equivalent in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently using the following formula in Google Sheets:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A13),if(isnumber(match(A13,Clients!A:A,0)),iferror(transpose(vlookup(A13,Clients!A:H,{2,3,5,6,7,8},))),"**no data**"),))
```

However, this is not valid in Excel. Is anyone able to help convert this?

Comment: have you tried keeping the rest of the formula, removing arrayformula and the brackets (), and just pressing CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER to enter it in excel as an array formula?

Comment: Try to provide the sample about your problem better than only provide a formula here.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?